# parse array of dictionaries from JSON with Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

there is a marketing API that responds with JSON like this:

```
{'page': 1,
 'total_pages': 1,
 'data': [
   {'day': '2018-06-11',
     'spend': 84.0,
     'clicks': 428,
     'impressions': 14778},
   {'day': '2018-06-12',
     'spend': 10.0,
     'clicks': 18,
     'impressions': 1778}
  ]
}
```

I would like to get a dataframe like this:

```
+----------+-----+------+-----------+
|       day|spend|clicks|impressions|
+----------+-----+------+-----------+
|2018-06-11| 84.0|   428|      14778|
|2018-06-12| 10.0|    18|       1778|
+----------+-----+------+-----------+
```

In regular python I can just do this:

```
response = requests.get(url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(response['data'])
```

But the solution must work in AWS Glue, and Pandas is unwelcome there. A solid day's searching has been fruitless. Some highlights:

Many suggest parallelizing it first, then turning the RDD into a dataframe:

```
response = requests.get(url).json()
rdd = sc.parallelize(response)
df = rdd.toDF()
```

But that results in:

> TypeError: Can not infer schema for type:

Others say this should bear fruit:

```
response = requests.get(url)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([json.loads(line) for line in response.iter_lines()])
```

But it results in this dataframe, which resists all attempts to parse:

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true) 
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- page: long (nullable = true)
 |-- total_pages: long (nullable = true)

+--------------------+----+-----------+
|                data|page|total_pages|
+--------------------+----+-----------+
|[Map(impressions ...|   1|          1|
+--------------------+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have almost solved it. In the snippet

```
response = requests.get(url).json()
rdd = sc.parallelize(response)
df = rdd.toDF()
```

The `response` is a nested JSON object and somehow dataframe is not able to infer the schema. Based on my understanding, you don't need the schema of the entire response object. What you are looking for is just the `data` field of `response` object.

So below snippet loads the data in the expected format:

```
response = requests.get(url).json()
rdd = sc.parallelize(response['data'])
df = rdd.toDF()
```

This same issue is there in your second approach as well.
Also, when creating the Dataframe using `createDataFrame` you don't need to load the `line` again as it will already be a json/dict object.
Below snippet should work:

```
response = requests.get(url).json()
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([line for line in response['data']])
```

Comment: First suggestion needed adjusting to `rdd.toDF(sampleRatio=0.5)`, but that's due to aspects of the source data that I left out of the question to keep things simple, so thanks!

The second gives `TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` but whatever.

Comment: Second solution had missing `.json()`. I just edited the answer. Thanks for pointing it out!