# How to expand nested JSON into Spark dataframe on AWS glue

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

Working with the following marketing JSON file

```
{
    "request_id": "xx",
    "timeseries_stats": [
        {
            "timeseries_stat": {
                "id": "xx",
                "timeseries": [
                    {
                        "start_time": "xx",
                        "end_time": "xx",
                        "stats": {
                            "impressions": xx,
                            "swipes": xx,
                            "view_completion": xx,
                            "spend": xx
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "xx",
                        "end_time": "xx",
                        "stats": {
                            "impressions": xx,
                            "swipes": xx,
                            "view_completion": xx,
                            "spend": xx
                        }
                    }
```

I can parse this using pandas very easily and obtain the desired dataframe in the format

```
start_time   end_time     impressions   swipes   view_completion    spend
    xx          xx             xx         xx            xx            xx
    xx          xx             xx         xx            xx            xx
```

but need to do it in spark on AWS Glue.

After creating an initial spark dataframe (df) using

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(JSON_resp['timeseries_stats'][0]['timeseries_stat']['timeseries'])
df = rdd.toDF()
```

I tried expanding the **stats** key as follows

```
df_expanded = df.select("start_time","end_time","stats.*")
```

Error:

```
AnalysisException: 'Can only star expand struct data types. 
Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(stats)`;'
```

&

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df_expanded = df.select("start_time","end_time").withColumn("stats", explode(df.stats))
```

Error:

```
AnalysisException: 'The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the 
number of columns output by the UDTF expected 2 aliases but got stats ;
```

Pretty new to spark, any help would be much appreciated for either of the 2 approaches!

It's a pretty similar problem as in:

[parse array of dictionaries from JSON with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960454/parse-array-of-dictionaries-from-json-with-spark)

except I need to flatten this additional stats key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `explode` a map column, it will give you two columns and so `.withColumn` is not working. Use `explode` with `select` statement.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.select('start_time', 'end_time', f.explode('stats')) \
  .groupBy('start_time', 'end_time').pivot('key').agg(f.first('value')).show()

+----------+--------+-----------+-----+------+---------------+
|start_time|end_time|impressions|spend|swipes|view_completion|
+----------+--------+-----------+-----+------+---------------+
|        yy|      yy|         yy|   yy|    yy|             yy|
|        xx|      xx|         xx|   xx|    xx|             xx|
+----------+--------+-----------+-----+------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! The only thing I had to do was declare ```import pyspark.sql.functions as f``` to get it to work.